# Could the net equations for burning hexene be used as a means of energy source?

Tags: energy, combustion, catalysis, fuel

1. $6\ce{CO_2} + 6\ce{H_2O}\xrightarrow{some\;catalyst}9\ce O_2 + \ce{C_6H_{12}}$
2. $\ce{C_6H_{12}} + 6\ce O_2\to 6\ce{CO_2} + 6\ce H_2$
3. $6\ce H_2 + 3\ce O_2\to 6\ce{H_2O}$

At one point, I had made a balanced set of equations while starting college. Those equations are listed above. I had wanted to get into chemistry to see if there was any possible way those equations could be used as a means for a new kind of energy source; one that could catalyze its fuel, hexene, that it could later use, but then also take the byproducts of the combustion of hexene and produce the same chemicals it needs to produce hexene, and repeat the process. I don't know if it's possible, and I don't know what, if any catalyst would be needed to make it possible. However, as time went on, my major changed to software development and I gave up on becoming a chemist. So this is both a question and a challenge: Can anyone figure out if the system described above is possible, and what would it require to make it available as an energy source?

Comment: To make this scheme available as an energy source, it should have an energy source. Now it has none. A catalyst, no matter how sophisticated, is not an energy source.

Comment: The energy source is in the second formula, in the same method as a combustion engine. A spark ignites the hexene fuel.

Comment: That, or I'm confused. The catalyst is definitely something relating to photosynthesis, but that's as far as I got with it.

Comment: Well, then 2 and 3 put together will bring you the exact amount of energy needed to pull off 1, minus the inevitable losses.

Comment: No, I meant hexene, since hexene is a combustible fuel. The formulas can't work with glucose.

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5445/photosynthesis-science-fair

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the mechanism of photosynthesis?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32153/what-is-the-mechanism-of-photosynthesis) or maybe of http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/696/energy-efficiency-aside-what-are-the-chemical-constraints-on-co%e2%82%82-capture-and-me ?

Comment: @Mithoron not a duplicate: this isn't about the mechanism of photosynthesis or the capture of $\ce{CO2}$. However, those posts are definitely helpful!

Comment: There is no such catalyst that makes 1. work without investing extra energy in the process, and this energy is as much (but generally much more ) than it is gained in 2,3., as already said by Ivan Neretin. So it is a no go.